# Why I can't download buildrot package in docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, buildroot

I am trying to build my own linux image using buildroot in docker with GitLab CI. Everything is going fine until I start downloading the "linux" repository. Then I get an error like below.

```
>>> linux d0f5c460aac292d2942b23dd6199fe23021212ad Downloading
Doing full clone
Cloning into bare repository 'linux-d0f5c460aac292d2942b23dd6199fe23021212ad'...
Looking up git.ti.com ... done.
Connecting to git.ti.com (port 9418) ... 198.47.28.207 done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
--2023-01-05 11:53:37--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux-d0f5c460aac292d2942b23dd6199fe23021212ad.tar.gz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 104.26.1.37, 172.67.72.56, 104.26.0.37, ...
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|104.26.1.37|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-01-05 11:53:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.
package/pkg-generic.mk:73: recipe for target '/builds/XXX/XXX/output/build/linux-d0f5c460aac292d2942b23dd6199fe23021212ad/.stamp_downloaded' failed
make: *** [/builds/XXX/XXX/output/build/linux-d0f5c460aac292d2942b23dd6199fe23021212ad/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The image being built without docker has no problem downloading this repository. I was building this image in docker a while ago and there was no problem downloading this repository. Could it be a problem of poorer network connection? The package is bigger than the others

Answer (score 1):

You are using a custom git repo (git.ti.com) which is not working and buildroot doesn't know anything about.

For this reason, you cannot expect a mirror copy available on sources.buildroot.net: buildroot only has copies of the packages distributed whithin it.